# Need to integrate sabre API into SOAP xml using Ktor framework

Tags: xml, soap, kotlin, sabre, ktor

I need to integrate sabre API into SOAP xml using Ktor framework(Kotlin), I'm not able to find any documentation regarding this.I'm looking for help regarding KTOR with SOAP XML API integration.

Comment: Sorry, I'am not aware of Sabre API. Are you looking for a way to create SOAP endpoint in ktor?

Comment: Or maybe you need ktor-client to make SOAP calls?

Comment: looking to create ktor-client to make SOAP call.